# background audio for video react-native-video

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-video

I am unable to get react-native-video to play mp4 files in the background, It will play mp3s and audio files but it refuses to continue playing the video. I have set the background modes in xcode to on with the audio, airplay and picture in picture selected as well as passing these props in as well

```
playInBackground={true}
playWhenInactive={true}
ignoreSilentSwitch={'ignore'}
```

is there additional configuration required when its a video and not just audio?

Comment: Please post the entire code you have written

Answer (score 6):

Try the code below:

```
<Video
    source={{uri: 'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4'}}
    style={{ width: 400, height: 400}}
    muted={false}
    repeat={false}
    resizeMode={"cover"}
    volume={1.0}
    rate={1.0}
    ignoreSilentSwitch={"ignore"}
    playWhenInactive={true}
    playInBackground={true}
  />
```

**Run your project from `Xcode` after doing the step below not just from `React-Native packager`.**

Set the `Capabilities` in `Xcode`:

[image]

Comment: now if app enters foreground, video player stays in little window